# Jackson JSON serialization of JPA Entities

Tags: jackson, jpa-2.0, resteasy

I have a JPA persistence layer with many @Entity classes which have many OneToMany and ManyToMany relationships.
I want to expose that entities by RestEasy with Jackson2 as serializer to JSON as REST services.

I know about @JsonIdentityInfo for resolving circular references.
The problem is in different REST services I need to expose different subsets of Entity fields. Moreover I need to expose different levels of depts for collections (OneToMany, OneToOne etc).
For example for this simple Entities:

```
class User {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Company company;
}

class Company {
    Long id;
    String name;
    List<User> users;
    List<Product> products;
}

class Product {
    Long id;
    String name;
    List<User> users;
}
```

and this REST service:

```
class MyResource {
    User getUser() { //... }
    List<User> getUsers() { //... }
    Company getCompany() { //... }
    List<Company> getComanies() { //... }
}
```

In method `getUser()` I need to return JSON with full User object including inner Company object. But that company of course only need to include their `id` and `name` field and not full list of users. Even more important that inner Company JSON must not include `products`! It is logical. If we get the user we don't need products of company that related to this user. If we need them we will send another REST request.

But in method `getCompany()` I need to return JSON with full Company object including inner JSON arrays of User and Product objects. Of course this time that User objects doesn't need to include inner JSON for Company object.

For this reason I can't use @JsonIgnore. In one case we need some field and in another we doesn't.

Now I came up with approach of using Jackson views (@JsonView annotation). I have View class with different views for every MyResource getter.

```
public class Views {
    public static class User {}
    public static class Users {}
    public static class Company {}
    public static class Companies {}
    // etc...
}
```

and MyResoruce class as

```
class MyResource {
    @JsonView(Views.User.class)
    User getUser() { //... }
    @JsonView(Views.Users.class)
    List<User> getUsers() { //... }
    @JsonView(Views.Company.class)
    Company getCompany() { //... }
    @JsonView(Views.Companies.class)
    List<Company> getComanies() { //... }
}
```

and have a MixIn classes for every Entity with every field annotated as

```
public abstract class UserMixIn {
    @JsonView({ Views.User.class, Views.Users.class, Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract Long getId();
    @JsonView({ Views.User.class, Views.Users.class, Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract String getName();
    @JsonView({ Views.User.class, Views.Users.class })
    public abstract Company getCompany();
}

public abstract class CompanyMixIn {
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class, Views.User.class, Views.Users.class })
    public abstract Long getId();
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class, Views.User.class, Views.Users.class })
    public abstract String getName();
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract List<User> getUsers();
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract List<Product> getProducts();
}

public abstract class ProductMixIn {
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract Long getId();
    @JsonView({ Views.Company.class, Views.Companies.class })
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Plurals for support cases where `getUsers()` doesn't need full inner Company object for every user (performance).
Of course there are just example classes. Real classes are much bigger and complex.

I do not like this approach because I am afraid that in the future it can be a nightmare (too many not manageable views). Maybe there are common approach for exposing JPA Entities as REST services? I believe it is a fairly common task. But can not find any intelligible information on how others doing this. Maybe some best practices.

Comment: Have you found a flexible solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I using just DTOs without doing too many optimizations. When I need optimizations I create another DTO for the same Entity with different fields. This is not optimal and I don't like this approach. I'm really looking forward to `Relay` framework from Facebook. It looks promising and will do exactly what many of us need - set required fields by *client*, not server.

Comment: We did not like the DTO approach and also cumbersome JsonViews. We were now trying to build custom serializers extending JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 2):

### Your service layer (and your REST controller layer) must expose [DTOs (Data transfer objects)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) instead of `@Entity` objects.

**Example :**

For a Service 1 (which focus on User managment) :

```
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private CompanyDtoLight company;
}

public class CompanyDtoLight {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

For a Service 2 (which focus on Company managment) :

```
public class CompanyDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    List<UserDtoLight > users;
    List<ProductDtoLight > products;
}

public class UserDtoLight {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

class ProductDtoLight {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

(The naming of your DTOs is yours)

**How to :**

You will need Mappers to transfom and reverse your `@Entity` to DTOs. Some lib exist like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) (there are plenty of other).

Comment: I know about DTOs. But it's not too flexible. What if I need for url /api/company/{id} to return CompanyDTO with full list of full Product (including inner list of users). And for url /api/company to return CompanyDTO as in your example (without)? I need another CompanyDTO2 with List<ProductDto>. I mean that for every small different view of same entity (include one more field in the entity or include one more field in related entity) I need another DTO which fully duplicate already existent DTO with difference in one field.
Maybe I'm too worried about problems that never arise.

Comment: This is the correct answer for building anything beyond simple applications. The domain logic should not bleed into the UI / web tier.